# How to increase the line length in ansible console output when using shell module?

Tags: shell, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have executed a command such as "df -h" on a machine using shell module as an ansible task. (using ansible version 2.14) For one of the filesystem, the mount point is lengthy. So,the complete output of the corresponding line is not displayed. I noticed that the output is truncated after 79 characters.

When the command "df -h" is executed manually on the same machine (after logging into via SSH), The output is displayed completely.

So, my question here is, is there any way to increase the line length limit so that the complete output is displayed in the ansible task output ?

Comment: What have you tried doing? Does the same result occur with ad-hoc commands?

Comment: Do you have any special configs for the `ansible.builtin.ssh_connection` module? `tty`?

Comment: Why is a mount point longer than 79 chars?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce. I'm using the same Ansible version.  The output of my command shows the full string.

```bash
# I've created a dummy mount w 91 chars:
[vagrant@vm-local-1 ~]$ df -h | grep ae
/dev/loop0                  7.8M   14K  7.4M   1% /aeTOQ27ggCJXVwKWT5HSHJf2EIjmyiF874lqLsehFMkymqQPUuWRqumMd4uayrmAbtMTHAW3SHpwAsXnoIjJbL5GAf
[vagrant@vm-local-1 ~]$ df -h | grep ae | awk '{print $6}' | wc -m
92
```

Then, I run the playbook and the output shows:

```yaml
- shell: df -h
  register: me

- debug:
    msg: "{{ me.stdout }}"
```

Output:

```bash
ok: [vm-local-1] => {
    "msg": "Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on\ndevtmpfs                    888M  228K  888M   1% /dev\ntmpfs                       907M     0  907M   0% /dev/shm\ntmpfs                       907M   17M  890M   2% /run\ntmpfs                       907M     0  907M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup\n/dev/mapper/rl_rocky8-root  125G  2.9G  123G   3% /\n/dev/sda1                  1014M  206M  809M  21% /boot\n/dev/loop0                  7.8M   14K  7.4M   1% /aeTOQ27ggCJXVwKWT5HSHJf2EIjmyiF874lqLsehFMkymqQPUuWRqumMd4uayrmAbtMTHAW3SHpwAsXnoIjJbL5GAf\ntmpfs                       182M     0  182M   0% /run/user/1000"
}
```

I don't know what you're trying to achieve.
What you can do is use `gather_facts: true` on play level, and then debug the mounts.  It should display the full string of the mount.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts }}"
```